# How to browse external webpage inside WebView

Tags: android, mobile-application

I create an android app to load external webpage inside WebView.
the problem when I press any link inside the app, it is open in web browser.
How to keep user browsing through my app?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To add a WebView to your Application, simply include the  element in your activity layout. For example, here's a layout file in which the WebView fills the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

To load a web page in the WebView, use loadUrl(). For example:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Before this will work, however, your application must have access to the Internet. To get Internet access, request the INTERNET permission in your manifest file. For example:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

That's all you need for a basic WebView that displays a web page.

Comment: I think he needs open all the urls of the page inside the same webview.